Abbreviations and text printed outside column regions
At times I find that abbreviations (e.g. Prof.) and initials (e.g. J.) produce a long period spacing.  How can I avoid this ?  Furthermore, with a two column document, I sometimes get text printed outside the column, but have no clue on how to avoid the situation.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

Il 23 febbraio 2024, lei ha ufficialmente inaugurato i Laboratori di
Ricerca e Innovazione in Ingegneria (ERIL) presso l'Università di Malta.
Durante il tour dei locali e delle attrezzature insieme al Rettore
dell'Università, Prof. Alfred J. Vella, sono state omesse alcune
osservazioni critiche.  Non è stata fatta alcuna menzione dei danni
causati dalla costruzione degli ERIL. 

\end{document}


Are you sure that there's extra whitespace after J.?

I do not know if it is an extra whitespace.  People use a shorter space after abbreviations and initials.  Somehow things look like an end of sentence.

Actually, while there is extra whitespace after Prof., there's none after J.

I see a space and (ERIL) is outside the column.

The issue of "(ERIL)" protruding into the right-hand margin is wholly unrelated to the main issue you've raised in this query, which is about .  prompting extra whitespace to be inserted even if the . character doesn't end a sentence. The extra space you claim to see in "J. Vella" is an illusion; change Alfred J. Vella to, say, Alfred J. Bella to verify this.

For the paragraph at hand, I see two ways of keeping "(ERIL)" from protruding into the right hand margin. First, you might choose to rewrite the paragraph suitably. Second, if a rewrite is not possible, I suggest you encase the paragraph in question in \begin{sloppypar} and \end{sloppypar} directives.

Yes, a solution is to rewrite.

Assuming the instruction \frenchspacing is not in effect, TeX and LaTeX follow a -- by now quite old-fashioned -- typographical convention that requires that sentence-ending . ("period", aka "full stop") characters be followed by a bit of extra whitespace. By default, TeX and LaTeX adhere to this convention, except if ". " is preceded by one or more uppercase characters.
Now, as you've noticed, not every . character ends a sentence. What to do in such cases?

You could, on a case by case basis, insert a backslash character between the . character and the subsequent whitespace character. E.g., you could make a habit of writing "Prof.\ " instead of just "Prof. ".

No need to change Alfred J. Vella to Alfred J.\ Vella, though.


If you have a desire to go deep into the gory TeX-y innards of this issue, I suggest you search for the term "\spacefactor" on this site.
Actually, the typographical convention of adding whitespace after sentence-ending periods is quite old-fashioned, and in practice it is more and more simply disregarded. The insruction \frenchspacing terminates adherence to this convention.
Finally, what to do if \frenchspacing is not in effect and if a . character does end a sentence? In that case, insert \@ immediately before the . character in question. E.g., if you use AI as the acronym for "artificial intelligence", you may want to change all instances of AI. to AI\@.. For more information on this subject, please see the posting What is the proper use of \@ (i.e., backslash-at)?
